# Extract hyperlink target from a cell in different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with a custom right click function that extracts cell values from another workbook depending on what the user chooses. It works very well, I just take in the cell's value from the other workbook. Some cells contain hyperlinks though, and I'd like to import the functional hyperlink, not the value of what's shown in the cell. For example, the following image contains a hyperlink in cell (Y216) of sheet BOS of the input workbook.:

[image]

This is an image of the cell I want to copy. It is indeed a hyperlink.

```
?application.Workbooks(2).Sheets("BOS").Range("Y216").value
```

returns MKB 70-203 Wicket Shear Pin Detection System, which is indeed correct.

But how do I take the hyperlink's destination? I tried several things including

```
?application.Workbooks(2).Sheets("BOS").Range("Y216").Hyperlinks.count
```

returns 0 even though you can see in the image that the hyperlink does have an address. In the same fashion the following sub doesn't enter the For Each because it counts 0  hyperlinks.

```
Sub HLtester()
    Dim HL As Hyperlink
    For Each HL In Application.Workbooks(2).Sheets("BOS").Range("Y216").Hyperlinks
        Debug.Print HL.Address
    Next
End Sub
```

Expected output would be the link's target `J:\SOUM\3191....` as shown in image.

EDIT

If it's important the cell's formula is

```
=LIEN_HYPERTEXTE("J:\SOUM\3191 M - Old Hickory Dam\11_BOS_FT\02_FT_MECT\21-200 Headcover";"21-200 Headcover")
```

That's the `=HYPERLINK` function of French Excel, by the way. I guess in last resort I can take the formula and cut off the `function` parts to retrieve the link part?

Comment: Have you checked out Workbooks(2).Sheets("BOS").Hyperlinks to see if there are hyperlinks present on the sheet, if not in that specific range? And if they're present, can you look through them and verify one is located at Y216?

Comment: @Mikegrann It returns no hyperlinks at all for the entire worksheet. Maybe there is something wrong with my hyperlinks? I tried them and they work. They were created with the =Hyperlink formula (not VBA). They all point to exterior references. `debug.print .Formula` gives `=HYPERLINK("J:\SOUM\3191 M - Old Hickory Dam\11_BOS_FT\02_FT_MECT\HM3191 00 MEF 32-202 F DA-01.pdf","HM3191 00 MEF 32-202 F DA-01.pdf")` So I guess I can just trim the formula around my target in worst case scenario...

Comment: well, I think that explains it. I'll dig around for it, but I'm fairly sure I've run into this before: hyperlinks created through the worksheet function are treated differently than inserted hyperlinks, and only the latter shows up in the `Hyperlinks` collection. Looks like you're going to have to manually extract the argument from `Range.Formula`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command works for me, I don't know why you set the range if you want to loop through all the hyperlinks in the sheet -neither why you set as application. workbooks-, anyways, this worked fine for me:

```
Sub HLtester()
    Dim HL As Hyperlink
    For Each HL In Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Hyperlinks
        Debug.Print HL.Address
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

You may get it as well within range methods with the following

```
ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
```

You may get more info [here](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/12/13/get-the-url-from-an-excel-hyperlink/)

**Edit:**

Probably the count is wrong because of the "application.workbook", try to declare it as a variable instead of using it all over the code

```
Sub HLtester()
    Dim HL As Hyperlink
    Dim WBAnalyzed As Workbook: Set WBAnalyzed = Workbooks("MyWB.xlsm")
    For Each HL In WBAnalyzed.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Hyperlinks
        Debug.Print HL.Address
    Next
End Sub
```

**Edit 2:**

 This is the approach suggested when the hyperlink it's given by its formula

```
Sub test()
    On Error Resume Next 'means no formula
    x = Evaluate(Range("A1").Formula)
    x1 = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Hyperlinks.Count
    Debug.Print x
    Debug.Print x1
End Sub
```

PS: I saved my variable declaration -just cause-, but, you should always have a neat control for them and use option explicit at the beginning of the module.

[image]

Comment: I'm doing it on a cell by cell basis in my example because that's actually what I want to do. I don't want to loop through every hyperlink in the sheet. I just want to extract the hyperlink from a specific cell. `ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address` gives an out of range exception for the reason I described in my question; the count of hyperlinks is 0. I set application.workbooks because the code is called from a certain workbook and the hyperlink is located in a second workbook. How else would you like me to access the second workbook's cells?

Comment: Why don't you declare a Workbook variable and then access to it instead of application.workbook? Check my updated response.

Comment: Oh that's definitely what I'm going to do once I get it working, but for now I don't see why application.workbooks would be the cause of the problem. I haven't inserted this in my code module yet so I was using it in a test sub. I'll try to avoid using it and come back to you -

Comment: OT: As you develop, you will see that you need to re define some excel bugs in their native functions that are not always accurate, one that I can think about right now is remove duplicates, in some scenarios, it doesn't do it accurately, same happens in VBA -even if the line is correct- the compiler has random errors time to time.

Comment: Still no results. Even the `.UsedRange` version gives 0 hyperlinks for the whole worksheet. I don't really understand why though, the cells have `=HYPERLINK("J:\SOUM\3191 M - Old Hickory Dam\11_BOS_FT\02_FT_MECT\HM3191 00 MEF 32-202 F DA-01.pdf","HM3191 00 MEF 32-202 F DA-01.pdf")` written in them or something similar. Does that look normal to you?

Comment: So, that's why, it's not a real hyperlink, it's given by a formula, let me re edit my answer